# CSS for nth-child() but ONLY if also matches a class

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I've seen some similar questions here, but nothing quite the same or that had the answer. I'm hoping what I'm trying to do is possible.

Basically, I have a top nav that is being generated inside WordPress. I want certain things to happen to the nav items on rollover and if they are the current-menu-item. But these things are different per nav item. I have the following CSS

```
.responsiveSelectContainer ul li:nth-child(1) .current-menu-item, 
.responsiveSelectContainer ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover{
    border-bottom: solid 3px #107B7E;
    color: #107B7E !important;
}
```

(1-6 for the six nav items, with different colors)

The a:hover part works just fine, but I can't make it use this CSS when the appropriate nav item also has the class of current-menu-item.

I tried with and without the space before `.current-menu-item` to no avail. What am I missing?

Thanks.

ADDING RELEVANT HTML (Generated by WP)

```
<div class="nav responsiveSelectContainer">
    <ul id="menu-top-menu-1" class="menu responsiveSelectFullMenu">
        <li class="oneLineNav strategy menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category current-menu-item menu-item-335"><a href="/strategy/">Strategy</a></li>
        <li class="managing-change menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-260"><a href="/managing-change/">Managing Change</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-3365"><a href="/leadership/">Leadership</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-3364"><a href="/transform/">Transformation</a></li>
        <li class="innovation-and-creativity menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-291"><a href="/innovation-and-creativity/">Innovation</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-3369"><a href="/corporate-culture/">Corporate Culture</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Again, the CSS works on the a:hover, just not on the .current-menu-item

I've also established that the CSS knows that's .current-menu-item by adding some other random CSS which it respected.

Answer (score 0):

The class is on the `li` itself, so it needs to go with the `li:nth-child(1)`:

```
.responsiveSelectContainer ul li.current-menu-item:nth-child(1), 
.responsiveSelectContainer ul li.current-menu-item:nth-child(1) a:hover{
    border-bottom: solid 3px #107B7E;
    color: #107B7E !important;
}
```

(Whether the class selector appears before or after the `:nth-child(1)` doesn't matter, I just place it before as convention.)

If the `!important` is merely a leftover of one of your attempts be sure to remove it if it is no longer necessary for the rule to apply.

Comment: In the end, the following worked:   .responsiveSelectContainer ul li:nth-child(1).current-menu-item a  The issue was that I was trying to edit the li when I should've been working on the a